# Does DotNetNuke 9 support OpenId Authentication Provider

Tags: openid, dotnetnuke, openid-connect, dotnetnuke-9

The documentation [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/manifest-authenticationsystem-component) suggests that DNN9 supports an OpenId Authentication Provider. But no such extension exists. Can you suggest how this can be enabled in DNN9?

Comment: Perhaps too late for you, but I've written an oidc provider and client for DNN. It's basically a POC, using IdentityServer4 to log in (using authorization_code), but anyone who is interested can use it as a starting point: https://github.com/Ruard/ProcsIT.Dnn.OpenIdConnect

Answer (score 2):

Besides its default authentication scheme, DNN 9.1.1 also included these authentication extensions:

- DotNetNuke Facebook Authentication Project
- DotNetNuke Google Authentication Project
- DotNetNuke Live Authentication Project
- DotNetNuke Twitter Authentication Project

None is installed by default, but can be installed from the Extensions control on the Persona Bar.

There is an OpenId project on Codeplex:  https://dnnauthopenid.codeplex.com/

But I don't see that it has been moved to GitHub, so that might indicate it's not up to date.

Comment: The current version of OpenId is OpenId Connect; the linked project is OpenId 2.0 which is older.